# Problem with bibliography compiling

Tags: bibtex, errors

I'm using Elsevier's `elsarticle` class to prepare my paper. 
There is a problem with compiling URL in bibliography. 
I have inserted the url with this format in `.bib` file(I'm using `bibtex`):

```
@misc{A23,
    title = {Malaysian Palm Oil Board},
    howpublished = {\url{http://mpob.gov.my}},
    note = {Accessed 12 February 2013 },

}
```

but the generated bibliography is as follow:

> Malaysian palm oil board, http://mpob.gov.my, ???? Accessed 12February
>   2013.

there are some question marks (????) in generated file. would you please help me with that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{url}                                                    \usepackage{amssymb}                                             \begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
.

Comment: That's a comment and it's not a minimal example! Extend the code and add it to the post above!

Answer (score 1):

The following code  produces correct output:

```
@misc{A23,
title = "Malaysian Palm Oil Board",
howpublished = "\url{http://mpob.gov.my}",
note = "Accessed 12 February 2013 ",
}
```

The output looks like:

> "Malaysian Palm Oil Board". http://mpob.gov.my. Accessed 12 February 2013.

Did you use `\usepackage{url}` in your preamble?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. yes I'm using url package